# Different colors for different facet subgroups in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have the following R code to generate a twins heights plot faceted by cohort and zygosity:

```
heights_plot = twinData %>% 
ggplot(mapping = aes(ht1, ht2)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(cohort ~ zygosity) 
+ ggtitle("Cohort and Zygosity Facet Plot by Similarity")
heights_plot
```

[image]

If I want to have, say, the upper left and bottom right subgroups be red and leave the others as is, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add a flag to the dataset and then do `color = flag` in `geom_point`

```
twinData$flag <- ifelse((twinData$cohort == 'younger' & twinData$zygosity == 'DZOS') |
(twinData$cohort == 'older' & twinData$zygosity == 'MZFF'), 1, 0) %>%
    as.factor()

twinData %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(ht1, ht2)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = flag, fill = flag)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "red")) + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red")) + 
facet_grid(cohort ~ zygosity) +
ggtitle("Cohort and Zygosity Facet Plot by Similarity")
```

You might need to flip the red and black but you should be able to utilize this code.

Comment: thanks for your help! If I have a tidy table named sig_twin_cor which contains a variable "similarity" that determines high correlation, how would I color only the high correlation subplots red? I have the following code but the result only shows 2 red subplots when it should be 5.                                                                                         sig_twin_cor$flag <- ifelse(sig_twin_cor["similarity"] == "Yes", 0, 1) %>% 
  as.factor()

Comment: Without seeing the data, I'm just taking a stab in the dark. I would create some sort of cutoff to determine what high correlation is: .7? .8? etc...
Then do:
`cutoff <- .8;` 
`sig_twin_cor$flag <- ifelse(sig_twin_cor[,"similarity"] > cutoff, 1, 0) %>% as.factor()`